# What's the difference between "svn merge --reintegrate" and svn merge without reintegrate if I'd like to merge a branch onto the trunk

Tags: svn, version-control

In the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.reintegrate) it says `merge`'s `--reintegrate` is "to merge all of the source URL's changes into the working copy".

I would like to merge a branch back to the trunk. [Some places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7071338/733034) say that it's "absolutely necessary" to call `reintegrate` when merging and then [delete the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816626/deleting-an-svn-branch) immediately afterwards, which I think is a hassle. [Other places](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Quick_SVN_merging_guide) do not mention reintegration at all. I have svn 1.6.11.

So I'm not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A *sync merge* is something completely different than a *reintegration merge*. The former is used to merge all changes made on the parent branch to the target branch (typically a feature branch), that have not already been merged. The latter is used to merge a (feature) branch back into the parent branch. Basically that means a temporary clone of the (feature) branch is created, a sync merge is made from the parent branch to the temporary branch, and finally the parent branch is replaced by the temporary branch. In other words, the temporary branch contains all changes made to the (feature) branch and parent branch.

For some reason, some developers do not understand the difference. So, the SVN developers removed the option `--reintegrate` in SVN 1.8. With this version, the tool detects automatically, if a *sync merge* or a *reintegration merge* should be used.

If you use an older version, you should use the option `--reintegrate` for *reintegration merges*. Note that the (feature) branch can still be used after reintegration, if you keep some things in mind. The SVN book explains it well:

- [Reintegrating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate)
- [Keeping a Reintegrated Branch Alive](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice)

Comment: Is "sync merge" just the plain `merge`, i.e. `merge` without `--reintegrate`?

Comment: Yes, a _sync merge_ is the default - without `--reintegrate`, `-c` and `-r`.

Answer (score 7):

Upgrade to svn 1.8 and don't worrry about it anymore, it will automatically figure out what to do.

from the [svn 1.8 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate):

> During merges which merge all eligible revisions from another branch, Subversion 1.8 will automatically decide whether or not the merge is reintegrating a branch. Therefore, reintegrating a branch does no longer require the --reintegrate option for correct operation.

Comment: Would I still need to delete the branch after the merge (merge --reintegrate)?

Comment: You don't have to delete the branch after a reintegrate if you follow [this little step](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice). I don't know why Subversion doesn't automatically do this for you.