# how to do svn reintegration of branches using command line

Tags: svn, merge, branching-and-merging, svn-reintegrate, svn-merge-reintegrate

I have created a new feature branch B from branch A.

Now I want to merge back the branch B into A and delete the branch B.

But I am getting confused about the two terms

- Merging the branch
- Reintegrating the branch

I don't understand how this two are different and how can I do that using svn command line.

Any helpful suggestions are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "svn merge --reintegrate" and svn merge without reintegrate if I'd like to merge a branch onto the trunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259353/whats-the-difference-between-svn-merge-reintegrate-and-svn-merge-without-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reintegration is a specific case of merging. Merge is a generic term. But when you merge **back** a branch (B in your case) to its parent (A), you are reintegrating.
`svn merge` used to have a `--reintegrate` flag before 1.8. This is deprecated, and you do not have to tell `svn` anymore that you are reintegrating. It is smart enough to figure it out.

In your copy of branch A, the command to merge branch B is:

```
svn merge URL-to-branch-B
```

Note that before 1.8, you could **not** reintegrate the same branch several times, although there is a workaround by manipulating `svn merge properties`. That is, once reintegrated, you had to delete the branch (best practice). I mention this, because you may collaborate with people with an older version of `svn`, and you (with the newer `svn` version) would have to do the merging if you plan to keep a branch alive after reintegration.