# svn merge vs reintegrate - Example wanted

Tags: svn, svn-reintegrate

After some reading with the intention to understand what is really svn reintegrate.

Can someone give an Example of:

svn merge of a branch to trunk
and
svn merge --reintegrate of a branch to trunk

Which give different results ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is the reintegrate option really necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680519/when-is-the-reintegrate-option-really-necessary)

Answer (score 2):

1. `svn merge` and `svn merge --reintegrate` produce the identical results, for `--reintegrate` options getting (internally) diff is just slightly easier
2. Best method **now** is

   - Migrate to SVN 1.8+
   - Forget about two styles of merge and use plain merge